# Unselect radiobutton not working when adding buttons programmatically

Tags: android

I add radiobuttons in code:

```
options.map {
                val radioOption = RadioButton(infoLabel.context)
                radioOption.text = it
                radioOption.isClickable = isReadOnly
                if (value.contains(it))
                    radioOption.isChecked = true

            infoRadioGroup.addView(radioOption)
        }
```

In options I have two elements. On start on of them is selected.When I start the app and try to select the second one I get two selected radiobuttons. The first one is still checked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen when the **Id** of both `RadioButton` are same. Make sure the **ID** of every `RadioButton` is unique.

Comment: Try to add id dynamically to your radio button before adding it to view.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem:

```
radioOption.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                    val count = infoRadioGroup.childCount
                    if (isChecked)
                        for (i in 0 until count) {
                            val radio = infoRadioGroup.getChildAt(i)
                            if (radio is RadioButton) {
                                radio.isChecked = radio.text == buttonView.text
                            }


                        }
                }
```